# Powermockito static method call

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I have a `class A` which has a static method `testA(String auditUser, Timestamp timestamp)` which calls a static method of `class B` if `auditUser` is `admin`. 
I am trying to write test for class A.
How can I verify the static method of B got called or not?

```
class A {
  public void static testA(String auditUser, Timestamp timestamp) {
    if ("admin".equalsIgnoreCase(auditUser) {
      B.testB(timestamp);
    }
  }
}

class B {
  public void static testB(Timestamp timestamp) {
  //...some logic...//
  }
}
```

Comment: use Mockito.verify();

Answer (score 0):

I add void to your static method for compile.

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(PowerMockTestRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(value = B.class)
public class TestClass {

    @Test
    public void testBAdmin() {
        String auditUser = "admin";
        Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(1577447182l);

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(B.class);
        //You can mock method here, if you need return value like this
        //when(B.testB(timestamp)).thenReturn("some_value");

        A.testA(auditUser, timestamp);

        PowerMockito.verifyStatic(B.class);
        B.testB(timestamp);
    }
    @Test
    public void testBNotAdmin() {
        String auditUser = "not_admin";
        Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(1577447182l);

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(B.class);
        //You can mock method here, if you need return value like this
        //when(B.testB(timestamp)).thenReturn("some_value");

        A.testA(auditUser, timestamp);

        PowerMockito.verifyZeroInteractions(B.class);
    }
}
class A {
    public static void testA(String auditUser, Timestamp timestamp) {
        if ("admin".equalsIgnoreCase(auditUser)) {
            B.testB(timestamp);
        }
    }
}

class B {
    public static void testB(Timestamp timestamp) {
//...some logic...//
    }
}
```

And don't forget about maven dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
  <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-beta.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
  <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-beta.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps:

1. Add `@PrepareForTest({ClassA.class, ClassB.class})`
2. These use `PowerMockito.mockStatic(ClassA.class);`, `PowerMockito.mockStatic(ClassB.class);`
3. The use `PowerMockito.when(ClassA.testA(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.any())).thenReturn(PowerMockito.when(ClassB.testB(ArgumentMatchers.any()))).thenReturn(any());`